# Can you tell me what this form is doing?

Tags: php, json, ajax, forms, onsubmit

I don't understand what this form is doing. I'm very inexperienced with Ajax and only somewhat experienced with PHP. I understand that the ajax.php is run after the form is submitted but I do not understand the onsubmit portion.

This form is returning an error "Error Parsing JSON" at the moment.

```
<form
    action="<?=$module->path?>/ajax.php"
    method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    class="tabmin_form"
    onsubmit="return handleAjaxForm(this, function(resp){AlertSet.addJSON(resp).show(); tabset_<?=$module?>.<?=$verb=='add'? 'getTab(\''.$tab.'\').reload(false)' : 'getTab(\''.$tab.$workshop->id.'\').close(false)'?>; tabset_<?=$module?>.getTab('view').show();}, function(resp) {AlertSet.addJSON(resp).show();})"
    autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: There should be a function in your JavaScript code called `handleAjaxForm()`. That is what the `onsubmit` is calling.

Comment: This form is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` is just inline event, ideally, for maintainability, you might want to abstract it out as its ugly.

---

Pull it out and format then break down each line.

`handleAjaxForm` - takes 3 args, first is the context second is the success callback and third is an error callback.

`AlertSet.addJSON(resp).show();` - passes resp to AlertSet.addJSON method then chains to show the alert with show() method.

the following is PHP working out what to pass the `tabset_module_name.getTab()` method or incase not `$verb == 'add'` it calls `.close()`.

`tabset_<?=$module?>.<?=$verb=='add'? 'getTab(\''.$tab.'\').reload(false)' : 'getTab(\''.$tab.$workshop->id.'\').close(false)'?>;`

then final line in the success callback:

`tabset_<?=$module?>.getTab('view').show();` which is calling the show method.

```
return handleAjaxForm(this, function(resp){
  //
  AlertSet.addJSON(resp).show(); 

  //
  tabset_<?=$module?>.<?=$verb=='add'? 'getTab(\''.$tab.'\').reload(false)' : 'getTab(\''.$tab.$workshop->id.'\').close(false)'?>; 

  //
  tabset_<?=$module?>.getTab('view').show();
}, function(resp) {
   AlertSet.addJSON(resp).show();
})
```

Long story short, the error is happening because `resp` is not JSON, check what your server is responding with, its most likely HTML

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Is there a way to designate this as the answer?This is my first time posting a question.

Comment: Can you explain more on what "resp" would represent? Or where it is set?

Also do you recommend a starting point for trying to understand this more clearly?

Comment: if *This is exactly what I was looking for.* then be sure to click the accept button